# Javascript Date object is different between Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting different dates for the same JavaScript in Safari and Chrome

`new Date("2019-11-29T14:00");`

returns `Fri Nov 29 2019 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)` in Chrome 
but Safari I get: `Fri Nov 29 2019 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)`

I'm not sure why - what am I missing?

Comment: What's the difference between those two values? They look the same to me.

Comment: I see no difference in these...

Comment: Bad proof-reading. I corrected it and found the reason why. Will share answer now

Comment: Your input string is not complete; it lacks a time zone indication after the time part. Thus browsers are free to interpret it however they please. If you add a "Z" to the end of the string, for example, you'll force the date/time string to be interpreted as GMT (UST).

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I found it eventually. Wondering if I should remove the question, there already is a post about it in my response

Comment: @Pointy—re "*it lacks a time zone indication … browsers are free to interpret it however they please*" no they aren't. An ISO 8601 format timestamp without a timezone or Z is to be treated as local. Safari is buggy.

Comment: @RobG well that may be the case; the point is that if you don't have a fully fleshed-out ISO date/time string things may not go so well.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wasn't using the time zone suffix: [Safari new Date with string value outs different time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210749/safari-new-date-with-string-value-outs-different-time)

Should be
`new Date("2019-11-29T14:00Z");` and now the dates are identical

Comment: Adding a "Z" changes the timestamp from local to UTC, so not a good solution (unless you wanted UTC, which is not what the timestamp is telling you). Safari's parser is buggy. 2019-11-29T14:00 **should** be treated as local, but Safari treats it as UTC. [Don't use the built–in parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).