# UTC Date Time to Full Date in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs, moment-timezone

How can i convert this `2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC` to `January 10, 2021?`

I'm using this below using moment.js but this works browsers but not in Safari
`{moment(video?.createdAt).format('MMMM D, YYYY')}`

Comment: try this: `moment("2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ").format("MMMM D, YYYY")`

Comment: @RohitKhanna. Thanks how about displaying the time? I tried displaying the time, its wrong. Its outputting 12:47 PM. It should be 8:47 PM.  `moment(video?.createdAt, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ").format('h:mm A z')`

Comment: On a side note, moment is deprecated https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moment.js is deprecated.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) Here's an alternative using native JS features.

First we need to convert the date string into a `Date` object. Calling `new Date(video?.createdAt)` is not reliable as mentioned on the [*`Date()` constructor* page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string):

> Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor
> (and `Date.parse()`, which works the same way)
> is *strongly discouraged* due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

See [*Date Time String Format* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#date_time_string_format) for reference of the correct format. For example:

```js
// This expects inputs in the form of
// `2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC`
function parseDate(dateString) {
  const [date, time] = dateString.split(' ')
  return new Date(`${date}T${time}.000Z`) // Z = UTC
}
```

Then we can use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format the `Date` object:

```js
// This expects inputs in the form of
// `2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC`
function parseDate(dateString) {
  const [date, time] = dateString.split(' ')
  return new Date(`${date}T${time}.000Z`) // Z = UTC
}

function format(dateString) {
  if (!dateString) return 'some fallback value'

  const date = parseDate(dateString)
  return date.toLocaleString('en', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
  })
}

console.log(format('2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC'))
//=> January 10, 2021, 2:47 PM

console.log(format(undefined))
//=> some fallback value
```

See [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) for all possible options. For example, these options produce slightly different results:

```js
return date.toLocaleString('en', {
  dateStyle: 'long',
  timeStyle: 'short',
})

format('2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC')
//=> January 10, 2021 at 2:47 PM
```

If the date strings can be in various formats, you probably need more robust date parsing. Or if you need exotic formattings, `toLocaleString()` might not meet your needs. In those cases, it might be useful to use one of the [recommended Moment.js alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/).

Comment: `new Date('2021-01-10 12:47:29')` would parse the date as local timezone instead of UTC

Comment: This is displaying as Invalid Date in Safari Browser

Comment: this is the value the real value not the one with z `2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC`

Comment: Its displaying RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: It says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: @Joseph Right, the input can be `undefined`. In that case you need to specify some kind of fallback value. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. How about the time? I wanted to display it like 8:47 PM? Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph Your original question didn't ask for time. :-) But yes, it's possible, I updated the answer. I also added a link which shows you all possible options.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why on Google chrome its correct 8:47 PM while on Safari its 6:17 PM?

Comment: @Joseph I'm getting the correct result on mobile Safari, so dunno. Might be related to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54210749. Maybe open a new question if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The new [Intl DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) API is gaining more support natively in many browsers, so it is a more future proof solution.  As suggested in the doc, you can use [polyfills](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-datetimeformat/) for browsers which lack full support of this feature.  Unfortunately, Safari is one of the browser which is yet to catch up.

A short snippet to achieve what you are looking for would be

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'long'}).format(new Date("2021-01-10 12:47:29Z"))  // outputs January 10, 2021
```

Keep in mind that date time string without `Z` at the end would be parsed as local time.  `Z` means the date time supplied is UTC.

Comment: this is the value the real value not the one with z `2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC`

Comment: Its displaying RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: The error is expected in Safari, you can include the [polyfills](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-datetimeformat/) which should patch the browser.  Overtimes the polyfills can be dropped when more browsers implement this API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for moment.js alternative, I would suggest [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format). Here is a [blog post](https://medium.com/@k2u4yt/momentjs-vs-date-fns-6bddc7bfa21e#:%7E:text=OOP%20momentjs%20and%20function%20date,might%20be%20reduce%20its%20size.) that compares the 2 of them.

Here is the [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format) documentation for date-fns.

So to answer your question using date-fns:

```
format(new Date(video?.createdAt), 'MMMM D, YYYY')
```

Comment: date-fns is nice. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string) that "Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse()`, which works the same way) is _strongly discouraged_ due to browser differences and inconsistencies."

Comment: @mtsknn I thought they discourage it because the string value doesn't have a timezone and is treated differently by diff browsers because of that local-tz inconsistency(?) In OP's case the date string he provided has a 'UTC', so should be good right?

Comment: `new Date('2021-01-10 12:47:29 UTC')` produces "Invalid Date" on Firefox and iOS Safari. Seems to work on Chrome. Dunno about other browsers.